# Are tattoos (particularly Japanese) carcinogenic and do they prevent sweating?

Tags: medical-science, cancer

I was reading an interview with [Jake Adelstein](http://www.abc.net.au/lateline/content/2010/s2998973.htm), a Yakuza expert, who says this:

> Also the tattoos. Like, you can see on the cover of this book and the back of this book - see, one of the things they tend to do is get these full-body tattoos which mark them as members of the Yakuza. And **the tattoos themselves are carcinogenic and they prevent your skin from sweating**.

The "stopping the skin from sweating" sounds like the [Goldfinger gold paint/skin breathing Urban Legend](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/201/if-you-were-painted-gold-as-in-the-movie-goldfinger-would-you-die), but is there any truth in the claims, particularly regarding Japanese ink and any potential nasties it might contain.

Answer (score -1):

There is a detailed explanation in Velo News about the connection between Tattoo and Sweating

> So to answer your question, I have to wager that some sweat gland
>   damage may occur and it’s a matter of speculation just how much. A
>   “full suit” tattoo would be more likely to have significant impact on
>   the sweat glands’ ability to maintain body temperature. I would
>   recommend having major work done in the off-season to allow the skin
>   ample time to heal and train back up to maximum sweat-gland function
>   before race season. Even with a full suit, there are many bare areas
>   that have no ink at all and are completely undamaged.[1](http://velonews.competitor.com/2006/01/training-center/ask-the-doctor-tattoos-and-beauty-are-skin-deep-2_9344)

[Velo News article about tattoos and sweating](http://velonews.competitor.com/2006/01/training-center/ask-the-doctor-tattoos-and-beauty-are-skin-deep-2_9344)

Comment: Sorry this is a poor reference: "The information contained in this column applies to general medical practice and may not reflect current medical developments or be interpreted as medical advice", find a better one if you can.

Comment: "and [to] train back up to maximum sweat-gland function" ?!? LOL

Comment: @Sklivvz isn't that a pretty standard disclaimer?

Comment: "I have to wager that" and "it’s a matter of speculation" implies that this is just personal guess, not a researched answer.